# Invisible, not transparent images for inactive attribute options in Configurable swatches

Tags: configurable-product, rwd-theme, swatches, color-swatches, attribute-options

I use the same attribute "color" for different "textures" of the product. I am using configurable swatches with magento default rwd theme. The problem is, when a certain texture in frontend is selected, ALL the colors are displayed, those that are not used are transparent. My question is: can I make them invisible or not shown at all?